# Express sending json but client receiving undefined

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, express, promise

I am running into a really frustrating issue. Where a simple json constant on the express server is sent as a json object, but when receiving this object, and trying to extract the errors from it on the client, the json object from the server comes through as `undefined` and for the life of me, I can't figure out why.

It seems that changing `res.status(400).json(errors);` to `res.json(errors);` from the server and extracting the error data from the client code block where isValid **is** true, I am able to get the error messages - therefore, sending the 400 status, may have something to do with it.

Has anyone else run in to this issue? i appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve.

Express - api.js

```
 if( isValid ) {
      res.json({success: true});
 } else {
      const errors = { username: 'This field is required',
                       email: 'Email is invalid' };

     res.status(400).json(errors);
 }
```

SignupForm Component

```
    this.setState({errors: {}, isLoading: true});
    this.props.userSignupRequest(this.state).then(
                    () => {
                        this.props.history.push('/');
                    },
                    ({data}) => {
                        console.log(data); //undefined
                        this.setState({errors: data, isLoading: false})
                    }
                )
```

SignupAction.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export function userSignupRequest(userData) {
    return dispatch => {
        return axios.post('http://myhost/api/signup', userData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible the request is being rejected before entering into the funciton from the first code snippet?

Comment: "It seems that changing res.status(400).json(errors); to res.json(errors); from the server and extracting the error data from the client code block where isValid is true." This is confusing to read, I have no idea what you are doing now.

Comment: what part is confusing? the second argument of `then()` handles bad responses, so if im not sending back a bad response status from the server, that code block doesnt get executed and I am able to get the json object successfully - it seems to resolve the undefined issue.

Comment: So how is `userSignupRequest` implemented?

Comment: @robertklep, with the axios package, see edited.

Comment: Its because in express when you use the status method, it returns an error, so you need to add a .catch statement onto the end of your .then

Comment: @DanielZuzevich, the second argument of `then()` handles bad requests

Comment: You are not doing it right, check Rafael's answer. That is a proper way to do it. Axios parses error messages weirdly as well. Notice how he has to chain a few things in the catch block. Its just how it is.

Comment: @DanielZuzevich, thanks for the help. See @robertklep's answer, you don't necessarily have to chain a `catch`.

Comment: Oh word. True that then. Was unaware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Axios manual](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#handling-errors):

> When using `catch`, or passing a [rejection callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) as second parameter of `then`, the response will be available through the `error` object as explained in the [Handling Errors](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#handling-errors) section.

So:

```
this.props.userSignupRequest(this.state).then(
                () => {
                    this.props.history.push('/');
                },
                error => {
                  const {data} = error.response;
                  console.log(data);
                  this.setState({errors: data, isLoading: false});
                }
            )
```

Comment: Nice. Just a quick note, you can perhaps also use the 'body-parser' npm module so you don't always have to type res.json on the express side. Check it out if you get some time.

Comment: @DanielZuzevich how is `body-parser` related to `res.json()`?

Comment: Yup its not, my mistake.

Comment: I think hes referring to: `app.use(bodyParser.json());` - not really related though hahaha

Comment: @AnchovyLegend I would assume you're already using `body-parser` since you're POST'ing to the server :D

Comment: Don't think I can delete that comment now, but yeah, I agree. Irrelevant suggestion.

Comment: @DanielZuzevich no problem :)